# connect to Cassandra CCM cluster with C# driver

Tags: c#, cassandra, cassandra-2.1, ccm

I am trying to play around with my application access a ccm cluster I create on the fly, for local development but I'm not sure how you would set the contact points (which ip address and what not, what security settings to use) once I've created my ccm cluster.

Any thoughts?  I will keep researching and post any answers I find back here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the number of servers you have created, they will be at `127.0.0.1`, `127.0.0.2`, etc. Unless you need to work with multiple clusters, you can simply connect use `127.0.0.1` address as contact point to connect to the cluster you have created.

Comment: Thanks!  I saw some people were adding mappings like
127.0.0.1   127.0.0.2   into their hosts file.  is that really needed if ccm sets up those other ip addresses for you?